# Failed to Import Module

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, servicebus, windows-server-2012-r2

I am using service bus for windows server. When trying to open the service bus command promt, getting below error. Could anyone please help me how to fix this?

```
Import-Module : The specified module 'ServiceBus' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have the module `ServiceBus` at the specified location?

Comment: Yes ServiceBus module is there in specified location. 

Didn't got the exact root cause but after [leaving the service bus farm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn441430.aspx) and [joining back the existing farm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn441386.aspx) has fixed the above issue

Answer (score 0):

Didn't get the exact root cause, but after [leaving the service bus farm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn441430.aspx) and [joining back the existing farm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn441386.aspx) the above issue was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Another cause of this error is permissions. Make sure the [Execution-Policy](https://ss64.com/ps/set-executionpolicy.html) is set to your desired level and that your powershell window is running with Administrative privileges so the scripts don't get blocked.